# How can I use the element tags from other custom directive as the template for another custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I'm relatively new to angularjs. I am creating a web application using angularjs on the client side.  I have made several custom directives and would like clients to be able to customize which directives they see each time they log in.  What I've attempted to do is create a string that is populated with the custom directive tags that a user selects. This information will be held as a cookie value and loaded by the controller when a user logs in.

This is the cookie value passed over (I've hard coded it for now):

```
public usersCustoms = `<div class="mdl-grid"> 
                                <div id="firstrow" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-grid" >
                                    <cit-recap > </cit-recap>
                                    <veh-ar-recap></veh-ar-recap>
                                    <new-models-inv></new-models-inv>
                                    <used-models-inv></used-models-inv>
                                </div>
                                <div id="secondrow" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-grid">
                                    <deal-recap></deal-recap>
                                    <vehicle-inv></vehicle-inv>
                                    <acct-trend></acct-trend>
                                </div>
                                <div id="thirdrow" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-grid">
                                    <parts-inv></parts-inv>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
```

Here are the directives the very last directive "usersCustomDirective" is the one that should pull the other directives in.

```
namespace DashboardDemo {
function citRecap(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/citrecap.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('citRecap', citRecap);


function vehArRecap(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/vehArRecap.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('vehArRecap', vehArRecap);

function newModelsInv(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/newModelsInv.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('newModelsInv', newModelsInv);

function usedModelsInv(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/usedModelsInv.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('usedModelsInv', usedModelsInv);



function dealRecap(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/dealRecap.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('dealRecap', dealRecap);


function vehicleInv(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/vehicleInv.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('vehicleInv', vehicleInv);


function acctTrend(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/acctngTrend.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('acctTrend', acctTrend);

function partsInv(): ng.IDirective {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'ngDashboardDemo/Views/Directives/partsinv.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardDemo.DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        }
    }

}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('partsInv', partsInv);

function usersCustomDirective(): ng.IDirective {
    return {

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //elem.html(scope.dc.usersCustoms);
            //console.log(scope.dc.usersCustoms);
            elem.html(scope.userOptions);

        },
        restrict: 'AEC',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        scope: {
            userOptions: '@userOptions'
        },
        //template: scope.userOptions

    }
}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('usersCustomDirective', usersCustomDirective);
```

}

Here is my HTML for the view:

```
<main class="mdl-color--grey-100">
<users-custom-directive user-options ="{{dc.usersCustoms}}"></users-custom-directive></main>
```

As its written now, the html doesn't display I'm assuming because html doesn't recognize my custom tags. I've also tried using elem.replaceAll in the link function but have gotten similar results. When I open developer tools in chrome, under elements I see my divs and my custom tags inside the divs, however, only the divs are being rendered, the custom tags are not. Thhe console has logged the string value that was passed in.  I've also tried changing "usersCustomDirective" to this:

```
function usersCustomDirective(): ng.IDirective {
    return {

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //elem.html(scope.dc.usersCustoms);
            //console.log(scope.dc.usersCustoms);
            console.log(scope.userOptions);

        },
        restrict: 'AEC',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        controller: DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        scope: {
            userOptions: '@userOptions'
        },
        template: scope.userOptions

    }
}
```

Instead of showing nothing in the html, it displays a string of the text I'm passing over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what I needed to do.  After further research, I needed to include $compile in the process. The changes I made were to add $compile into the directive function call. Then I assigned the template the scope.userOptions value. I called $compile on the template and viola angularjs magic.  Works great now.  Hopefully this helps someone else.  FYI if you're using typescript, like me and you get an error saying: 'property blank does not exist on type IScope', you'll need to create an interface of your own and extend IScope to include the property

```
function usersCustomDirective($compile): ng.IDirective {
    return {

        link: function (scope: IMyScope, elem, attrs) {
            var template = scope.userOptions;
            var linkFn = $compile(template);
            var content = linkFn(scope);
            elem.append(content);

        },
        restrict: 'AEC',
        replace: true,
        controller: DashboardController,
        controllerAs: 'dc',
        scope: {
            userOptions: '@userOptions'
        },

    }
}
angular.module('DashboardDemo').directive('usersCustomDirective', usersCustomDirective);
```